# How to a press tab in python with selenium

Tags: python

everybody, I'm new to python and I need some help because I'm trying to press tab in python but it won't work I've checked so many tutorials on Stackoverflow but none of them seem to work for me I am making a bot that automatically updates my public ip :( here is my code

```
    from webbot import Browser
    from json import load
    import requests
    import getip
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    web = Browser()
    web.go_to('https://my.freenom.com/clientarea.php? 
    action=domaindetails&id=1045379216') 
    web.type('MyEmail' , into='username' ,id = 'username')
    web.type('MyPass' , into='Password' , id='password') 
    web.click('login')
    web.click('Manage freenom DNS')
    ip = getip.get()
    web.type('',id="records[0][value]")
    NEED TO PRESS TAB HERE 3 TIMES
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "press tab"? Are you trying to enter a tab charater in your IDE? Or have the bot enter a tab on the web page you have it browsing? None of your code seems to be trying to press tab, so it's not clear where you want it to happen or what problems you might be having.

Comment: @BlckknghtI am making an auto IP updater for my .tk domain and need it to press tab 3 times over were I said I needed to (At the bottom)

Comment: @Omar:  When you say "None of them seem to work for me" what you should do is show *in code* what you tried to do to make them work.  Something like "The answer to question X says to do Y.  Here is my attempt to do Y.  I also tried the answer to question Z and here is my attempt."  Then detail any error messages (literally cut-and-paste them) and describe what happens in the browser.  The more *relevant* detail you add, the more likely you are to get an answer.

Answer (score -1):

Copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/26628620/564514

Using Java:

```
WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath(""));//You can use xpath, ID or name whatever you like
webElement.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
webElement.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

Comment: hey @paragbaxi, how do I put java inside python?